# Problem on Root Systems

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $R$ be a root system on a Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}$ with simple roots $\{\alpha_i : i=1,....,l\}$.
If $\alpha$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{l}c_i\alpha_i$ be a root , then show that 
$\frac {c_i(\alpha_i|\alpha_i)}{(\alpha|\alpha)}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $\forall$ $i$ = $1, 2....,l$.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which inner product you denote by $(\cdot\mid\cdot)$? There tend to be about a million different ones floating around when dealing with root systems, and which ones have which properties (and why) depend on which one it is.

Comment: (.|.) is a symmetric bilinear form on E which is invariant under the Weyl Group.